# C++ read integers from file and save into array

Tags: c++, arrays, integer

I'm making a program that reads only integers from text file.  I want to make a function that reads integers and stores them in an array so I can use that array later to sort them with bubble sort. This is what I have so far but the output I get is some random -803234.... number :

```
void read(int A[max], int& numbers) { 
    ifstream file("ints.txt");
    if (file.is_open()) {
        file >> numbers;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
            cout << "numbers: " << A[i] << endl;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    cout << "numbers in array: " << A[numbers] << endl;
}
```

Comment: You should read the numbers inside the for loop.

Comment: Where in the code is `A` filled up with numbers?

Comment: You should be using a Standard Library container instead of a fixed-sized array here. What is `max` and how can you be sure it's sufficiently big?

Comment: Can you paste your output so we can get a better idea what's going on?

Comment: If you to get help on this expose what you have in "ints.txt". As @EdHeal said, A is never touched.

Comment: @Jon Please no, it's already easy to spot what's going on. `A[i]` is never read in from the file.

Comment: in ints.txt i have integers like totaly random 2 3 55 322 45 21 and so on

Comment: what do you mean by A is never touched?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but note that in the argument list here, `int A[max]` is the same as `int A[10]` is the same as `int A[]` is the same as `int* A`. In most cases, the name of an array decays into a pointer to the first element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't store the numbers in the array at any point:

```
void read(int A[max], int& numbers) { 
    ifstream file("ints.txt");
    if (file.is_open()) {
        file >> numbers;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
            // you're printing A[i] but you haven't stored
            // anything there.
            cout << "numbers: " << A[i] << endl;
```

I assume that `numbers` is the number of entries in the file and that you intended to read the values the same way you read `numbers` but into A[i].

```
cin >> A[i];
```

The last part of your code also tries to print beyond the last entry of the array:

```
cout << "numbers in array: " << A[numbers] << endl;
```

Remember, C++ arrays are 0 based, so `A[numbers]` is the *numbers + 1*th entry.

Comment: at what point do you store integers in your array, in for loop?

Comment: Since this looks like an educational assignment, I'm not going to give you the full working example, but it should be obvious that you need to read->store them before you try to print them. See where I put my comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::vector<int> read_ints(std::istream& is)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(is),
              std::istream_iterator<int>(),
              std::back_inserter(result));
    return result;
}
```

If you can't use vectors, you've got a problem because you now need to check for end of file and for running out of space in your array...

this function will check for both, and return the number of integers that have been placed into the buffer:

```
template<size_t N>
size_t read_ints(int (&dest)[N], std::istream& is)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < N && is >> dest[i]) {
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

non-template version:

```
#define BUFFER_LEN 100

size_t read_ints(int (&dest)[BUFFER_LEN], std::istream& is)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < BUFFER_LEN && is >> dest[i]) {
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: As the poster is a novice a bit of explanation would not go amiss.

Comment: i shouldn't be using vectors, sorry i should say that in description

Comment: @vidooo updated in response. If you can't use templates, replace N with a number of choice.